# Select box text align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello every one i want to text align center bootstrap select box option values i try inline style for text-align:center; but my select box values still in left align. Any one knows how to center align values plx help me out of this.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap sometime style element overridien by parent style so you have to add `!important`

If you have class '`td-text-center`' in td then you have to add style like

```
.td-text-center {
    text-align : center !important;
}
```

Comment: I already use !important; with text-align:center but nothing happen.